# Do Laws of Secants and Cosecants exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If they exist, what are they and where do they come from? If they do not exist, why not?

For context, I am a high school math teacher and we were studying Law of Sines and Cosines in our Honors Precalculus course. One of my students asked about Law of Tangents, and discovered that both it and a Law of Cotangents exist, but we were unable to find Laws of Secants and Cosecants.

Comment: "laws" as in straightforward geometric relations, that allow you to compute an area or length given some angles/lengths? (as the sine and cosine rules do)